# Fetch top two domains from query

Tags: sql, db2

Example data:

```
Name       | Domain    | Count | datetime
-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------
John       | google    | 5     | 2019-07-09 01:00:01
John       | apple     | 6     | 2019-07-09 01:02:01
John       | apple     | 8     | 2019-07-09 01:03:01
John       | google    | 10    | 2019-07-09 01:11:01
John       | dos       | 1     | 2019-07-09 01:11:01
John       | dos       | 3     | 2019-07-09 01:11:01
```

Expected output:

```
Name      | max_Domain1 | max_Count1 | max_Domain2 | max_Count2 | datetime
----------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------
John      | google      |    10      | apple       |      8     | 2019-07-09
```

I tried using row_number() over the partition, but it is giving me the same date values as top 2 maximum.

```
select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, date(datetime) order by count desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      where datetime >= '2019-07-08' and
            datetime < '2019-07-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then domain end) as domain_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then count end) as count_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then domain end) as domain_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then count end) as count_2,
       date(datetime)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, date(datetime) order by count desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      where datetime >= '2019-07-08' and
            datetime < '2019-07-09'
     ) t
group by name, date(datetime);
```

Comment: it is not working as expected. please check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=0424400ef0ad83b6ef5c164286dd9f2f

Comment: @Knot . . . The results in the dbfiddle are exactly what is labelled "expected results" in your question.  I think this works.

Comment: no its not. check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8b435e7b6c4c4647503fda59d89a43bd